# VSCode C++ compile with own header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linker-errors, header-files

How do I convince VSCode to compile my C++ program with my own header files? I just can't figure it out.

Minimal example with the following directory structure:

```
workdir/main.cpp
workdir/test.h
workdir/test.cpp
```

Content of the `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    print_stuff();
}
```

Content of `test.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once

void print_stuff(void);
```

Content of `test.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void print_stuff()
{
    std::cout << "Stuff" << std::endl;
}
```

From the command line, compiling with `g++ -o main.exe main.cpp --std=gnu++17 test.cpp` works. Even VSCode's intellisense correctly finds the functions, but still can't compile.

I've tried modifying the `includePath` in the `configurations.json`, but so far without any success:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: You need to edit your `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json` if these header files are in some different folder from your .cpp files. Also if you don't edit your `tasks.json` file VSCode by default only attempts to build the active file into the executable. You will get link errors in that case. The documentation explains how to have it compile all .cpp files in your folder instead of just the active file here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: I don't see you including ```test.h``` in ```test.cpp``` probably a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but the problem was twofold. This post helped:
[Why is Visual Studio Code ignoring my tasks.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958296/why-is-visual-studio-code-ignoring-my-tasks-json-file)

As @drescherjm pointed out, I had to modify my `tasks.json` to include all *.cpp files:

```json
            "args": [
                "-O3",
                "${workspaceFolder}/backend/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/backend/main.exe",
                "-std=gnu++17",
                "-fopenmp"
            ],
```

But there seems to be a bug in VSC that changes to the ´task.json´ are not considered right away. Everytime I changed something in the file, I had to restart VSC to take effect.